# how to loop random.randint(0, 1000) to print all resuts at once line by line?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

as mentioned in the title:

I'm trying to loop this so it prints all results line by line :

```
k=random.randint(0, 1000)
```

I'm using batch file to keep printing the random numbers but it is very slow:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
k.py
goto start
```

how can i do this in python ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all results." `random.randint(0, 1000)` only produces ONE result -- ONE number in the range `0 --> 1000` (inclusive)

Comment: If you want all of those numbers in a random order, why not use `random.shuffle`?

Comment: @Adam Smith yes it prints only ONE result , im trying to make it to keep printing. thats why i made the batch file.

Comment: @xhxx forever? `while True: print(random.randint(0, 1000))`

Comment: for i in range(1000): print ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

# prints an endless list of random numbers
while True:
    num = random.randint(0, 1000)
    print(num)
```

other alternatives:

```
# print 1000 random numbers
for i in range(1000):
    num = random.randint(0, 1000)
    print(num)
```

or

```
# print the numbers 0..1000 in random order
nums = list(range(1001))
random.shuffle(nums)      # shuffle list in-place
for num in nums:
    print(num)
```